# how to store both string and integer in a single 2d array in c++ ? Is it possible? How? I want following results:

Tags: c++, c++17

```
1    vikram jha   1999    local
2    ravi kr      1998    outsider
3    anil         2000    outsider
4    john         1999    local
```

here is a 2d array of size [4][4],
I want to store these information in a 2d array. How to do it ? Is it possible in a single array?
I am a binger
. other ideas are also welcomed.

Comment: Are the items in each row related to one another? If so, you might want to define an object for the item that has attributes and then have a 1d array of those objects.

Comment: yes, items in each row are related to each other. Creating 1d array for row each will be my last choice.

Comment: Why would 1d array of objects be your last choice? It should be your first. For your case you could use a simple `struct` for your item/object. Inside the `struct` you can have two strings and an `int`. I assume the first value is just an index for your array.

Answer (score 3):

**Code**
It uses std::vector as container(dynamic size) with std::tuple as elements or struct as elements.

It also can be C-style array[n] as container(fixed size) with std::tuple as elements or struct as elements.

It also can be std::array as container(fixed size) with std::tuple as elements or struct as elements.

With tuples you don´t need to create complex types, simply add the dessired types for tuple elements, but the syntax in my opinion I see it uglier, the programmer can fall into errors when he makes a mistake when writing an index of an element of the tuple.

With structs you can create a complex type with functions, fields, constructor. The syntax is simpler, clearer. If you want to use a field, you refer to it by name rather than by an index, thereby reducing typing errors.

I prefer to use the classes provided by the standard c ++ library, you can do more with data types, they come with vitamins(std::array, std::vector). On the other hand, using the arrays in c-style has to do a little more work and reinvent the wheel that already exists with the standard c ++ library. For productivity as a developer and for simplicity in the code I prefer the C ++ classes.

```
#include <iostream> //to reference std::cout.
#include <string> //to reference std::string
#include <tuple> //to reference std::tuple
#include <vector> //to reference std::vector

//Function. Get total of UTF8 chars in string. u8"█"s contains 1 char but it needs 4 bytes to store in std::string. u8"@" contains 1 char but it needs 1 bytes to store in std::string
//UTF8 char size in bytes can be from 1 to 4 bytes.
size_t TotalUTF8Chars(const std::string &data)
{
    size_t ret = 0;
    for (char value : data)
    {
        if ((value & 0xc0) != 0x80)
        {
            ++ret;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

//Function for add padding chars at right of string, if string total utf8 chars is greater than total width, it returns same string. 
//Example data = u8"█", totalwidth = 5, paddingchar= u8"", the result is u8"█...."
//Example data = u8"", totalwidth = 10, paddingchar= u8"", the result is u8""
//  needs 4 bytes
//Padding char can be only 1 utf8 char length.
std::string PadRight(const std::string &data, const size_t &totalWidth, const std::string &paddingchar)
{
    if (TotalUTF8Chars(paddingchar) > 1)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument(u8"Invalid padding char length.");
    }
    std::string ret = data;
    if (TotalUTF8Chars(data) >= totalWidth)
    {
        return ret;
    }
    size_t charsToAdd = totalWidth - TotalUTF8Chars(ret);
    for (int i = 0; i < charsToAdd; i++)
    {
        ret.append(paddingchar);
    }

    return ret;
}

/* 
Struct for store the 4 values.
*/
struct Person
{
    int id;//field
    std::string name;//field
    int year;//field
    std::string locality; //field
    
    Person(int id, std::string name, int year, std::string locality) //Constructor / function that allow create new Person with the values of parameters.
    {
        this->id = id; //Initialize the struct field with the value of parameter. The keyword "this" is needed for differentiate field(id) from struct vs parameter(id).
        this->name = name;
        this->year = year;
        this->locality = locality;
    }
    Person() //Constructor //Create new empty/default Person //this constructor is needed for example array of structs
    {
        //Initialize the struct field with default values.
        this->id = 0; 
        this->name = "N/A";
        this->year = 0;
        this->locality = "local";
    } 
};

int main()
{
    //With std::vector of tuples //Dynamic size array // Can be insert any number of elements. //https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector
    std::cout << "█ With std::vector of tuples" << std::endl;
    std::vector<std::tuple<int, std::string, int, std::string>> persons;//Declaring and create new std::vector<tuple<>>
    persons.push_back(std::tuple<int, std::string, int, std::string>{1, u8"vikram jha", 1999, u8"local"}); //Insert new tuple element at end of vector
    persons.push_back(std::tuple<int, std::string, int, std::string>{2, u8" ravi kr", 1998, u8"outsider"});
    persons.push_back(std::tuple<int, std::string, int, std::string>{3, u8"anil", 2000, u8"outsider"});
    persons.push_back(std::tuple<int, std::string, int, std::string>{4, u8"Anna", 1999, u8"local"});
    persons.push_back(std::tuple<int, std::string, int, std::string>{5, u8"Mary", 1999, u8"local"});
    persons.push_back(std::tuple<int, std::string, int, std::string>{6, u8"Joseph", 1999, u8"local"});
    persons.push_back(std::tuple<int, std::string, int, std::string>{7, u8"Tony Stark", 1999, u8"Stark Industries"});

    for (std::tuple<int, std::string, int, std::string> person : persons) //Range-based for loop, iterate over range of elements.
    {
        //std::get<N>(tupleVariable) where N is the index of field. In this case have 4 fields 0 - 3. 0 = id, 1 = name, 2 = year, 3 = locality 
        std::cout << "Id: " << std::get<0>(person) << "| Name: " << std::get<1>(person) << "| Year: " << std::get<2>(person) << "| Locality: " << std::get<3>(person) << std::endl; //Printing values
    }

    //With std::vector of structs ////Dynamic size array // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector
    std::cout << "█ With std::vector of structs" << std::endl;
    std::vector<Person> persons2; //Declaring and create new std::vector<Person>
    persons2.push_back(Person{1, u8"vikram jha", 1999, u8"local"});//Initialize new Persona / Using the parameterized constructor in the struct and insert at end of vector.
    persons2.push_back(Person{2, u8" ravi kr", 1998, u8"outsider"});
    persons2.push_back(Person{3, u8"anil", 2000, u8"outsider"});
    persons2.push_back(Person{4, u8"john", 1999, u8"local"});
    persons2.push_back(Person{3, u8"anil", 2000, u8"outsider"});
    persons2.push_back(Person{7, u8"Tony Stark", 1999, u8"Stark Industries"});
    
    for (Person person : persons2)
    {
        std::cout << "Id: " << person.id << "| Name: " << person.name << "| Year: " << person.year << "| Locality: " << person.locality << std::endl;
    }

    //With C-style array of tuples // Fixed size array. //https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array
    int n = 4;
    std::cout << "█ With C-style array of tuples" << std::endl;
    std::tuple<int, std::string, int, std::string> persons3[n];
    persons3[0] = {1, u8"vikram jha", 1999, u8"local"};
    persons3[1] = {2, u8" ravi kr", 1998, u8"outsider"};
    persons3[2] = {3, u8"anil", 2000, u8"outsider"};
    persons3[3] = {4, u8"john", 1999, u8"local"};

    for (std::tuple<int, std::string, int, std::string> person : persons3)
    {
        std::cout << "Id: " << std::get<0>(person) << "| Name: " << std::get<1>(person) << "| Year: " << std::get<2>(person) << "| Locality: " << std::get<3>(person) << std::endl;
    }

    //With C-style array of struct // Fixed size array. //https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array
    n = 4;
    std::cout << "█ With C-style array of struct" << std::endl;
    Person persons4[n];
    persons4[0] = Person{1, u8"vikram jha", 1999, u8"local"};
    persons4[1] = Person{2, u8" ravi kr", 1998, u8"outsider"};
    persons4[2] = Person{3, u8"anil", 2000, u8"outsider"};
    persons4[3] = Person{4, u8"john", 1999, u8"local"};
    //using for instead of foreach
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Id: " << persons4[i].id << "| Name: " << persons4[i].name << "| Year: " << persons4[i].year << "| Locality: " << persons4[i].locality << std::endl;
    }

    //With std::array of struct // Fixed size array // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array
    const size_t n2 = 4; //std::array needs constant value for size. 
    std::cout << "█ With std::array of struct" << std::endl;
    std::array<Person, n2> persons5; //Need fixed length, constant value.
    persons5[0] = Person(1, u8"vikram jha", 1999, u8"local");
    persons5[1] = Person(2, u8" ravi kr", 1998, u8"outsider");
    persons5[2] = Person(3, u8"anil", 2000, u8"outsider");
    persons5[3] = Person(4, u8"john", 1999, u8"local");
    for (Person person : persons5)
    {
        std::cout << "Id: " << person.id << "| Name: " << person.name << "| Year: " << person.year << "| Locality: " << person.locality << std::endl;
    }

    //Complex example with text formatting
    //With std::array of tuple // Fixed size array. // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array
    std::cout << "█ With std::array of tuple" << std::endl<<std::endl;
    typedef std::tuple<int, std::string, int, std::string> MyPersonTuple; //reducing the name of the data type and avoid writing std::tuple<int, std::string, int, std::string>
    std::array<MyPersonTuple, 4> persons6{MyPersonTuple{1, u8"vikram jha", 1999, u8"local"},
                                           MyPersonTuple{2, u8" ravi kr", 1998, u8"outsider"},
                                           MyPersonTuple{3, u8"anil", 2000, u8"outsider"},
                                           MyPersonTuple{4, u8"john", 1999, u8"local"}}; //Another form of initialization of std::array using initialization list of MyPersonTuple type. Check typedef
    
    //Print headers
    std::string headers = PadRight(u8"█ Id: ", 15, u8" ") + PadRight(u8"█ Name : ", 15, u8" ") + PadRight(u8"█ Year: ", 15, u8" ") + PadRight(u8"█ Locality: ", 15, u8" ") + "█";
    std::cout << PadRight(u8"", TotalUTF8Chars(headers) , u8"█") << std::endl;
    std::cout << headers << std::endl;
    std::cout << PadRight(u8"", TotalUTF8Chars(headers) , u8"█") << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
    {
        //Print elements
        size_t max_size = 13;
        std::string id = PadRight(std::to_string(std::get<0>(persons6[i])), 13, u8" "); //Converting element 0 from tuple element to string -> Padding with spaces
        std::string name = PadRight(std::get<1>(persons6[i]), 13, u8" "); //Padding with spaces second element of tuple.
        std::string year = PadRight(std::to_string(std::get<2>(persons6.at(i))), 13, u8" ");
        std::string locality = PadRight(std::get<3>(persons6[i]), 13, u8" ");
        std::cout << "█ " << id << "█ " << name << "█ " << year << "█ " << locality << u8"█" << std::endl; //Print padded values.
    }
    //Print footer
    std::cout << PadRight(u8"", TotalUTF8Chars(headers) , u8"█") << std::endl;
}
```

**Console's output**

```
clang++-7 -pthread -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp
./main
█ With std::vector of tuples
Id: 1| Name: vikram jha| Year: 1999| Locality: local
Id: 2| Name:  ravi kr| Year: 1998| Locality: outsider
Id: 3| Name: anil| Year: 2000| Locality: outsider
Id: 4| Name: Anna| Year: 1999| Locality: local
Id: 5| Name: Mary| Year: 1999| Locality: local
Id: 6| Name: Joseph| Year: 1999| Locality: local
Id: 7| Name: Tony Stark| Year: 1999| Locality: Stark Industries
█ With std::vector of structs
Id: 1| Name: vikram jha| Year: 1999| Locality: local
Id: 2| Name:  ravi kr| Year: 1998| Locality: outsider
Id: 3| Name: anil| Year: 2000| Locality: outsider
Id: 4| Name: john| Year: 1999| Locality: local
Id: 3| Name: anil| Year: 2000| Locality: outsider
Id: 7| Name: Tony Stark| Year: 1999| Locality: Stark Industries
█ With C-style array of tuples
Id: 1| Name: vikram jha| Year: 1999| Locality: local
Id: 2| Name:  ravi kr| Year: 1998| Locality: outsider
Id: 3| Name: anil| Year: 2000| Locality: outsider
Id: 4| Name: john| Year: 1999| Locality: local
█ With C-style array of struct
Id: 1| Name: vikram jha| Year: 1999| Locality: local
Id: 2| Name:  ravi kr| Year: 1998| Locality: outsider
Id: 3| Name: anil| Year: 2000| Locality: outsider
Id: 4| Name: john| Year: 1999| Locality: local
█ With std::array of struct
Id: 1| Name: vikram jha| Year: 1999| Locality: local
Id: 2| Name:  ravi kr| Year: 1998| Locality: outsider
Id: 3| Name: anil| Year: 2000| Locality: outsider
Id: 4| Name: john| Year: 1999| Locality: local
█ With std::array of tuple

█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████
█ Id:          █ Name:        █ Year:        █ Locality:    █
█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████
█ 1            █ vikram jha   █ 1999         █ local        █
█ 2            █  ravi kr     █ 1998         █ outsider     █
█ 3            █ anil         █ 2000         █ outsider     █
█ 4            █ john         █ 1999         █ local        █
█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████
```

You can check/run this code on  https://repl.it/@JomaCorpFX/Tuples-and-Struct

**References**
[UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)
[std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)
[C-style array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array)
[std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)
[std::tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)
[Range based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Comment: Good effort, but code-only answers are of limited usefulness to others. Why would you use a vector of tuples over a vector of struct? Why would you use a vector over a plain-old 2D array? All of these are likely considerations that are lost on the OP.While your code is well formatted and easy to read for someone who already knows what you are doing, it may be a stretch for beginners. Take a bit more time and add a few paragraphs explaining to the OP why you did what you did. That said, your effort is worth a nod.

Comment: Thanks. Updated answer. Added some comments in code and some opinions from this code.